# My css is hides an image when I change it

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why this is happening.

I have a perfectly icon showing, however, when I change the image, it stops showing, only when I hover over it.

I cannot change the HTML, only css elements.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="div-menu-win">
 <ul class="menu-win">
  <li>
   <div title="Ajuda" class="iconWin manual"></div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My css with the image working

```
ul.menu-win li .manual, ul.menu-win li .manual::after 
{
background-image: url('../images/ico_aj.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 16px 16px;
}

ul.menu-win li .manual,
ul.menu-win li .manual:after
{
background-image: url('../images/ico_aj.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;  
background-size:16px 16px;
}
```

There is a message there, Filter rules containing this property

And when I change the background image, that image disappears.

Any thoughts?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Something else is overriding it. Check further up in the rules list. The other part is the `::after` needs to have a `content:`, `display:`, `width:` and `height:` properties or you won't ever see the background image on the pseudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some more CSS rules. Try setting the size, the content property (required for ::after and ::before metaselectors), and the display type... as an example :

```
width:20px;
height:20px;
content:' ';
display:block;
```